# Может ли фрагментация таблицы влиять на взаимоблокировки?

Tags: sql-server

Например, есть таблица, где фрагментация 95%, а заполняемость страниц 50%.

Так вот, я параллельно пытаются обновить данные из разных соединений, которые ну никак не пересекаются между собой и одно из соединений отваливается с сообщением, что один процесс заблокировал другой.

Никаких транзакций там тоже нету.

Может ли фрагментация влиять на то, что блокировки накладываются неэффективно?

Могу ошибаться, но вроде, наличие первичного ключа не гарантируется, что на соседних страницах будут данные отсортированы, а SQL Server может применять блокировку страниц, которая может быть расширена и захватить соседние, а так как там могут быть не соседние данные, то блочим что-то лишние. Повторяюсь, могу ошибаться.

В упрощенном виде:

Есть процедура, которой на вход подается Pack_id.

Есть таблица T вида : `ID, Pack_id, XDocument`

ID-PK кластеризованный

Pack_id некластеризованный индекс

Первым запросом, я делаю выборку данных в таблицу @Data

```
SELECT rec_id,a.e.value("(@id)[1]",'nvarchar(36)') as TRID,NewId() Ord FROM T
CROSS APPLY XDocument.nodes('root/TableRow') a(e)
WHERE PACK_ID=@PackId
```

По идее, таблица @Data не должна превышать 100 записей.

Дальше, я выбираю N записей отсортировав их по Ord (Получаются случайные N записей) и иду через Cursor :

```
UPDATE T
SET XDocument.modify('insert <Node>0</Node> into (root/TableRow[@id=sql:variable("@TRID")])[1]')
FROM T
WHERE T.ID=@ID
```

Т.е может происходит много одиночных обновлений. При этом исключается то, что кто-то параллельно обновляет одно и тоже.

В итоге, что-то отваливается со взаимоблокировкой. Хотя, на мой взгляд ее быть не должно.

Если данные сначала сливать во временную таблицу и там обновлять XML, а потом одним разом накатывать, то проблемы нету.

Comment: *Одно из соединений отваливается с сообщением, что один процесс заблокировал другой* - какое конкретно сообщение? Дедлок или лок таймаут? Добавьте сообщение в вопрос.

Comment: @DenisRubashkin дедлок.

Comment: В Extended Events сессии `system_health` можно найти граф дедлока (xml_deadlock_report), посмотрите что там к чему, если не разберетесь - добавьте XML в вопрос

Comment: @i-one Да я там XML-ку в несколько подходов обновляю. Я дополнил вопрос.

Comment: @i-one да, дополнил.

Comment: Если нет явной транзакции, курсор читает только из @Data (не делая join опять к T), то чисто умозрительно ничего криминального, вроде бы, нет.

Comment: @i-one ну вот и я о том же... Просто, большое кол-во одинарных кротковременных обновлений, которые вообще никого блокировать не должны. Вот когда я все это в темповые таблицы начал сливать и по ним курсоры делать, а потом 1 обновлением переносить готовые XML в основную таблицу, то проблема исчезла.